# How to do a recursive Boolean method? Currently only returning true

Tags: c++, recursion

```
**Hey guys I'm new to c++ and I've been trying to get some practice with it.
```

I have this method for checking if palindrome that I want to return a bool.
I want to do this recursively. The
Any input?**

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string word)
{
    
    if (word.length() == 0 || word.length() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (word.at(0) == word.at(word.length() - 1))
    {
       return  isPalindrome(word.substr(1, word.length() - 1));
    }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you have any actual problem with this code? Does it crash? Does it return a wrong result?

Comment: `word.substr(1, word.length() - 1)` should be `word.substr(1, word.length() - 2)`.  It'll still be pretty inefficient though, since it makes a bunch of copies of `word`.  Consider making `word` a `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` if you're using C++17 and have access to that.

Comment: The second parameter of `substr` is the length of the substring. So you are one out in your calculation, it should be `word.length() - 2`. Now think about this, can you find a solution that does not use the inefficient `substr`?

Comment: Your code was better before you made the edit. Add `return false;` to the end of your function.

Comment: To check a `std::string` is a palindrome you could simply compare it to the [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) version of itself - one line of code; done.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string word)
{
    
    if (word.length() == 0 || word.length() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (word[0] == word.at(word.length() - 1))
    {
       return  isPalindrome(word.substr(1, word.length() - 2));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I had mistakenly removed the return false when I added the word.length() - 2

Comment: Glad to help, but please don't edit the code in the question because it makes a nonsense of the replies you got. Someone looking at this question in the future is not going to see your original problem, and is not going to understand the replies.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I set the question back to its original status.